# Hosting WCF service (http binding) in Windows Service (Multithreading)

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, c#-3.0

i have a question about hosting WCF service in a Windows Service. When the Windows Service runs inside an instance of ServiceHost.

The question is related to threading:

Do I need to configure ServiceHost, so that every time it is accessed and created a separate instance of the WCF service? If so, how this can be done?

And also I have a question:

If there is a lot of requests to the service, ServiceHost itself solve all the problems with the thread pool, or need to track yourself?

Comment: have you explored InstanceContextMode and ConcurrenyMode attributes.
Refer - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and

Comment: did you get any solution ?